# fetchUserRecordID Cloudkit error: Couldn't get container configuration

Tags: core-data, swiftui, cloudkit, ios14

My app is written in SwiftUI using Cloudkit to store records from Core Data. I'm able to get records using `@FetchRequest` to populate a list. Now I want to get the current user's iCloud ID and compare it to another global ID, but I'm having issues with `fetchUserRecordID`...

I'm able to see user records when looking at Cloudkit Dashboard's `Users` record type. But every time the code below runs I get the following error: "Couldn't get container configuration from the server for container "iCloud.com.my_container_name""

I'm running Xcode 12.2 Beta 4

`ContentView.swift`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    init() {
        isCreator()
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
   
      Text("Hello World")   

    }

    func isCreator() {
        
        CKContainer.default().fetchUserRecordID(completionHandler: { (recordId, error) in
            
            guard let record = recordId, error == nil else {
                print("Error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            
            print("Found record")
            // Now do something with record...
            
        })
        
    }

} // end ContentView
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.name_of_your_container")` instead of `CKContainer.default()`

My issue was that I named my Cloudkit container `testapp` and my app's bundle id was `com.my_team_name.testapp`. When running Cloudkit queries, I kept getting this error:

`Couldn't get container configuration from the server for container "iCloud.com.my_team_name.testapp"`

After looking at the Cloudkit Dashboard I realized that my container's name was literally only "testapp."

Once I changed my code to `CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.testapp")`, it worked just fine.